# Why is class copied instead of referenced?

Tags: c#, value-type, reference-type

I've been trying to figure out for some time why sometimes I get a copy of my data and sometimes a reference. Then I found out about `reference types` and `value types`. So my life changed and I started using this info when coding.

Now I am making a custom editor in Unity. I have an `Ability` class, which contains a `Buff` list (list of Buff classes). So each ability that i have can contain multiple buffs.

When editing the ability variables in the database, I first get a copy of the ability that I am using to not edit them directly but to edit the copy and then save the copy into the database when done. However I still seem to make copies with one line and not with the other. So now it seems I am not referencing a reference type but making it behave like a value type. I don't understand why this is.

```
//This constructor is used to make a copy of an existing Ability in the database
public Ability(Ability cloneFrom)
{
    buffs = new List<Buff>();

    //This will work, not cause a reference but actually takes a copy.
    //I don't understand that because I am using Add()on a class (reference type)
    for (int x = 0; x < cloneFrom.buffs.Count; x++)
        buffs.Add(cloneFrom.buffs[x]);

    //This will create a reference as expected
    buffData = cloneFrom.buffData;
}
```

The only thing I could imagine is that List.Add() actually makes the copy, but I haven't been able to confirm.

Comment: I think it depends on the type that is added.  A simple variable is copied and added, but a complicated type like a class it is only linked.

Comment: What is `Buff`? If its a class, then it will be referenced in both lists, however the lists will not reference each other. If its a struct, its copied by value to the new list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Really quick, make sure you understand the difference between a `class` and an `object`.  A **class** is the cookie cutter; an **object** is the cookie.

I think Ron Beyer (from the comments) hit the nail on the head -- you're probably saying you want to keep the lists in sync so that the `buffs` of one `Ability` **object** stay in sync with another `Ability` object.

This will only work if you assign one object's buffs to another's.

If you call `Add`, then you'll get a reference to the buff, but new buffs will not be added.

You mentioned value vs reference types; the quick list is as follows (someone jump in here and correct me)

**Value types**

- primitive types (int, float, long, double, bool, etc.)
- structs
- enum

**Reference types**

- classes
- delegates
- interfaces
- object

There is one case you should be aware of:

```
public class Ability {
    public int Score { get; set; }

    public Ability(int score) {
        Score = score;
    }
}


public static void KillReference(Ability ability) {
    // When we execute the next line, the ability
    // from the original scope will stay the same
    ability = new Ability(2);
}

public static void Main() {
    Ability ability = new Ability(5);

    KillReference(ability);

    // ability.Score is still 5
}
```

**OHGODWHY**

When you pass a reference type to a function, you're effectively passing a "copy" of a reference (this is the same with pointers in C/C++)...you're effective passing a reference by value (confusing, right?).

When you assign that reference to another object, the original object that was referenced is no longer referenced by this variable -- there's a new variable and all changes to `ability` will be directed at this new variable (which will be cleared from the heap once you exit the function's scope).

Hope that helps!